# How to write SQL queries with respect to the following conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database table in which a column `tags` contain values such as:

```
"AutoMNRP, MNRP"
"Macro, MNRP"
"AutoMNRP, Micro"
"Macro, Micro"
```

where `"...."` represents a string.

I want to write a SQL query such that it filters out all results having MNRP tag in it. How can I do this?

I tried a not like operator of SQL on it, but if I want to remove MNRP tag, it also filters out AutoMNRP tag.

At the last of query I need results featuring -

```
"AutoMNRP, Micro"
"Macro, Micro".
```

(Results when MNRP is filtered out.)

Comment: Is the unwanted "Mnrp" always preceeded by ' ,' ? Then you can use `Not like '%, MNRP%"` This won't eliminate "AutoMNRP"

Comment: No MNRP, can be at any place. I can be at the first one or the only tag as well.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server you have?

Comment: Ideally, if you can, you should be splitting out this data before you store it in your database. If this value will also has 2 (or less) parts it should be 2 columns perhaps. If it could be any number, then you should have a further to store the many to one (or even many to many) relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right answer to this is to fix your design, you shouldn't store the data like this (comma separated), because your table should be like (and the duplicates should be removed and handled too)

```
+----------+
|   Data   |
+----------+
| AutoMNRP |
| MNRP     |
| Macro    |
| MNRP     |
| AutoMNRP |
| Micro    |
| Macro    |
| Micro    |
+----------+
```

But... here is a way it may fit you requirements

```
;WITH T(Str) AS
(
 SELECT 'AutoMNRP, MNRP' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Macro, MNRP' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'AutoMNRP, Micro' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Macro, Micro'
)
SELECT Str
FROM T
WHERE Str NOT LIKE '% MNRP,%' 
      AND
      Str NOT LIKE '%, MNRP';
```

**Returns:**

```
+-----------------+
|       Str       |
+-----------------+
| AutoMNRP, Micro |
| Macro, Micro    |
+-----------------+
```

**[`Live Demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=092698a127fc0eeb7d72c75e29af81d3)**

You also (as [Larnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3484879/larnu) point to) do as

```
;WITH T(Str) AS
(
 SELECT 'AutoMNRP, MNRP' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Macro, MNRP' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'AutoMNRP, Micro' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Macro, Micro'
)
SELECT Str
FROM T
WHERE CONCAT(', ', Str, ',') NOT LIKE '%, MNRP,';
```

Comment: You could convert this to a single `LIKE`  by doing `WHERE ', ' + Str + ',' NOT LIKE '%, MNRP,'`. As a leading wildcard is expensive that could be a bit of an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2016+ you can use the `STRING_SPLIT` function. So you can multiply a record by the number of separated values in the `tags` column so you can then apply a simple `WHERE` clause. Something like this:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT Id, SingleTag
    FROM table_name CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(tags, ',')
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE SingleTag = 'MNRP'
```

Comment: I *think* the OP wants `!=` not `=`, as they state that `'MNRP'` should be filtered out.

Comment: @Larnu And `DISTINCT` too since it's a `CROSS APPLY`, still you can have a [test](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=92e1c7ce56a35dd5a35fc0901e9ccb17) always :)

Comment: Actually, now I think about it, as this is normalising the data, it should be `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: You're right guys, but my intention is to show how to split the string then use usual T-SQL `WHERE` to build your filter...All valid points though...

Comment: @BozhidarStoyneff . . . `string_split()` doesn't work on this example because the separator is two characters, not one.